# Trouble parsing XML into JSON - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, highcharts

I am trying to parse some XML data into JSON using Javascript/Jquery for use in a Highcharts project. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what is wrong with my code as it will not even read the XML. So far I have:

xml:

```
<Row>
    <Category>data</Category>
    <actual>data</actual>
</row>
....
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var globalData = new Array();

// $("h1").click(function(){
    // Load the data from the XML file 
    $.get('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\xmloutput.xml', function(xml) {
        alert("it works");

        // Split the lines
        var $xml = $(xml);

        // push series
        $xml.find('Row').each(function(i, row) {
            var seriesOptions = {
                Category: $(series).find('Category').text(),
                Actual: $(series).find('Actual').text(),
            };

            // add it to the options
            globalData.push(seriesOptions);
        });


    });
// });


$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                borderColor: '#000000',
                innerSize: '60%'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: globalData
        }]
    },
    // using 

    function(chart) { // on complete

        var xpos = '50%';
        var ypos = '53%';
        var circleradius = 102;

    // Render the circle
    chart.renderer.circle(xpos, ypos, circleradius).attr({
        fill: '#ddd',
    }).add();

    // Render the text 
    chart.renderer.text('THIS TEXT <span style="color: red">should be in the center of the donut</span>', 155, 215).css({
            width: circleradius*2,
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px',
            textAlign: 'center'
      }).attr({
            // why doesn't zIndex get the text in front of the chart?
            zIndex: 999
        }).add();
    });
});


});
```

I believe my actual problem may be that my xml-parsing syntax is incorrect but running this on the development console in Firefox reveals no errors. Hopefully the experts here can spot the issue(s)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to use webserver to load files by $.get() function.

Answer (score 2):

One imediate problem that I can see is using local path

```
$.get('C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Desktop\\xmloutput.xml',
```

`$.get` first parameter is url that is location on network it could be something like `$.get('http://localhost/xmls/xmloutput.xml,...`

Comment: Does not fix the problem, as I cannot see anything new happen. Probably means I have more issues with the code :(

Comment: you can read xml from path that is within your web application, put xml you want to read into the folder where that code for website is and then `http://localhost[port that you are using]/xmloutput.xml`. Website cannot see `C:` only things that are inside it's folder.

Comment: Is there a default port that I would be unknowingly using? This website is just a prototype as of now and is not hosted yet

Comment: default port is 80 but if there is no port when you are accessing your website then just use `http://localhost`